# AspectJ - Why put transaction control in a seperate place?

Tags: aop, aspectj

Ok, I haven't fully understood the philosophy why AOP AspectJ is good for. I have now implemented a Logging and transaction control for when withdrawing money from a bankaccount. Alright, why is it good in doing that? I could likewise implement the control in the same class file where I've also stored all my banking methods (withdraw, deposit, balance... etc). And the logging I could've create a new class for it, and thereafter make an instance of it in the BankAccount class.

So why do I need to use AOP, AspectJ for it? I haven't fully understood the idea...

Here's my aspect file

```
public aspect SafeWithdrawal {                                                                                  

pointcut checking(BankAccount bk, float x): execution(* BankAccount.withdraw(float)) && target(bk) && args(x);                                                                                                   

public static void BankAccount.LogChange(String str){                                                    
    System.out.println(str);                                                                             
}                                                                                                        


before(BankAccount b, float x) : checking(b, x) {
        if(b.getBalance() >= x) {
            BankAccount.LogChange("Account changing. $" + x + " withdrawn...");
        } else {               
            BankAccount.LogChange("Account does not have. $" + x + " to withdrawn...");
        }

}                                                                                                        

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that your domain methods like withdraw can remain laser-focused on your business processes and secondary concerns like logging, transactions, profiling, etc. don't get in the way.

Comment: "laser-focused"? So the idea is not to clutch your function with things that is not related to the method itself? Well then there's a whole lot of things that need to be changed into aspects, isn't? I thought the idea with OOP already covered that though.

Comment: @starcorn: How does OOP address crosscutting concerns?

Comment: @starcorn: The above comment isn't terribly constructive.  The idea behind AOP is that each class has a single responsibility.  Your bank account class' purpose is to handle transactions, it's not to implement a caching policy or to implement logging or uniform exception handling.  The logging classes responsibility is to log all errors (for example), caching policy's responsibility is to cache values, etc.  Then you can specify at the application level how logging/caching/etc is handled and have that rule apply everywhere.  But each of those pieces of information is only specified once.